# creating menu in Android

Tags: android

I am creating android application which involves menu.Can anyone provide me the sample code code of creating menu.
Thanks in advance

Tushar

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

For your pleasure, *some* code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

Comment: samy can u put some source code plzz

Comment: the code is well documented on the given page... where is the problem?

Comment: Both the links point the the same thing. and it already has the code.

Comment: Thanks sheikh,,But if u put the url,,it will be more beneficial

Comment: lol, wtf is wrong with you? :D

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)